# Как запустить magnific popup после отправки данных из формы обратной связи?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup

Подключил *Magnific Popup* к форме отправки данных пользователя.

Нужно, чтобы после нажатия кнопки «Отправить» исполнялась функция открытия всплывающего окна Magnific Popup-а.

```
$("#main_form").submit(function() { //Change
   var th = $(this);
   $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "mail.php", //Change
     data: th.serialize()
   }).done(function() {
     //судя по всему код должен быть тут
     setTimeout(function() {
       // Done Functions
       th.trigger("reset");
       $.magnificPopup.close();
     }, 3000);
   });
   return false;
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

Вроде решение нашлось:

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
    items: {
        src: 'some-image.jpg'
    },
    type: 'image'
});
```